# Как сохранить показ рекламы после блокировки

Tags: admob

Google Play в свете новых правил удалил приложение. Автоматически Admob делает соответствующий рекламный идентификатор неактивным. Это значит реклама в уже установленных приложениях тоже перестает отображаться. Хочу подстраховаться на будущее.

Посоветовали обернуть в

```
if (Interstitial.IsReady())
... 
else if(UnityAds.IsReady()) 
...
```

Но я не могу понять что и как обернуть, и как оно должно работать.